# How to show events from device calendar in my app?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, calendar, ionic-framework

I'm on an ionic-app and need to show the last 2 or 3 events from the calendar of my iPhone. Moreover I need to put the attributes from the events (time, location etc.) in variables.

I tried that with the [Cordova-Calendar-Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin) from Eddy Verbruggen. Creating calendars, adding events etc. works fine but how can I fetch the data from the calendar and show it in my app?

Comment: I see where you can do a "findEvent" with this plugin, but I don't see how to just list calendar events (with iOS).  Looking at the EventKit documentation from Apple, this doesn't seem to be an iOS limitation.  I am sorry I don't have more information.